# Laravel Package development: Facade alias not found

Tags: laravel-7, php-7.4, package-development

I try to create an alias for a facade in a Laravel 7 package.

On testing I get the message:

> Error: Class 'MemberRequest' not found

Test:

```php
    /** @test */
    public function a_member_request_can_be_created()
    {
        $this->assertDatabaseMissing('member_requests', ['created_at' => Date::now()]);
        \MemberRequest::create(new CreateMemberRequestRequest(['email_address' => $this->email_address]));
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('member_requests', ['created_at' => Date::now()]);
    }
```

I did the following steps:

- create a facade (extending the facade class from Laravel Illuminate
- Register it in the service provider
- add the alias to the config file
- add the alias to the composer.json file

Create a Facade:

```php
namespace martijn\UMS\Repositories\Facades;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade;

class MemberRequestRepositoryFacade extends Facade
{
    public static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'MemberRequest';
    }
}
```

Register in serviceProvider:

```php
namespace martijn\UMS\Providers;


use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use martijn\UMS\Repositories\MemberRequestRepository;

class UMSBaseServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function register()
    {
        $this->registerFacades();
    }

    private function registerFacades()
    {
        // Facades
        $this->app->singleton('MemberRequest', function () {
            return new MemberRequestRepository();
        });
    }
}
```

Add it to a config file:

```php
return [


    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Class Aliases
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This array of class aliases will be registered when this application
    | is started. However, feel free to register as many as you wish as
    | the aliases are "lazy" loaded so they don't hinder performance.
    |
    */

    'aliases' => [
        'MemberRequest' => \martijn\UMS\Repositories\Facades\MemberRequestRepositoryFacade::class,
    ]
];
```

Add it to composer.json:

```
      "aliases": {
        "MemberRequest": "martijn\\UMS\\Repositories\\Facades\\MemberRequestRepositoryFacade"
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that it is done in the boot loader of the service provider like this:

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-class-aliases-in-package

In my example it was:

```php
$loader = AliasLoader::getInstance();
$loader->alias('MemberRequest', \martijn\UMS\Repositories\Facades\MemberRequestRepositoryFacade::class);
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `ServiceProvider`, try like this:

```php
$this->app->singleton('MemberRequest', function () {
   return new MemberRequestRepository;
});
```

Comment: Same error:  > Error: Class 'MemberRequest' not found